# delphi определить есть ли символы юникода в строке

Tags: delphi, кодировка

нужна функция которая вернет есть ли в строке юникод или нет.
как это делает блокнот
https://prnt.sc/bGbowOL4WHwk

причем блокнот разрешает сохранить рус буквы в ansi
я нашел в модуле widestr функцию
это почти то что надо только она вернет Utf8 и для русских букв хотя нужно как у блокнота
только когда есть юни коды типа смайлы

```
function DetectUTF8Encoding(const s: RawByteString): TEncodeType;
var
  c : Byte;
  P, EndPtr: PByte;
begin
  Result := etUSASCII;
  P := PByte(PAnsiChar(s));
  EndPtr := P + Length(s);

  // skip leading US-ASCII part.
  while P < EndPtr do
  begin
    if P^ >= $80 then break;
    inc(P);
  end;

  // If all character is US-ASCII, done.
  if P = EndPtr then exit;

  while P < EndPtr do
  begin
    c := p^;
    case c of
      $00..$7F:
        inc(P);

      $C2..$DF:
        if (P+1 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 2)
        else
          break;

      $E0:
        if (P+2 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$A0..$BF])
            and ((P+2)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 3)
        else
          break;

      $E1..$EF:
        if (P+2 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$80..$BF])
            and ((P+2)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 3)
        else
          break;

      $F0:
        if (P+3 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$90..$BF])
            and ((P+2)^ in [$80..$BF])
            and ((P+3)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 4)
        else
          break;

      $F1..$F3:
        if (P+3 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$80..$BF])
            and ((P+2)^ in [$80..$BF])
            and ((P+3)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 4)
        else
          break;

      $F4:
        if (P+3 < EndPtr)
            and ((P+1)^ in [$80..$8F])
            and ((P+2)^ in [$80..$BF])
            and ((P+3)^ in [$80..$BF]) then
          Inc(P, 4)
        else
          break;
    else
      break;
    end;
  end;

  if P = EndPtr then Result := etUTF8
  else Result := etANSI;
end;
```

думаю что это просто набор байт с разными диапазонами может с этой функции нужно лишнее исключить и и тогда она будет возвращать только если есть юни кода смайлы. ток я не уверен что именно нужно удалить. а какие диапазоны оставить

Желаемый результат

```
     s:=  '';
     if Detect(s) then  // true


     s:=  'рус';
     if Detect(s) then  // false

     s:=  'eng';
     if Detect(s) then  // false

     s:=  'русeng';
     if Detect(s) then  // true
```

Походу дела возник вопрос еще один как код символа перевести в набор байт? И возможно ли это?

```
 s:='А';//рус А
 i:=ord(s[1]);//1040
 //как 1040 перевести в набор байт (208,144) что возвращает 
 Arr.Arr:= TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

### TEncoding (Delphi)

Я начал путь здесь -> **[Класс TEncoding](http://citforum.ru/programming/delphi/unicode/2.shtml)**

Библиотека Tiburon RTL также включает новый класс TEncoding. Его назначение - определить конкретный тип кодировки символов, чтобы можно было сообщить библиотеке VCL, какой тип кодировки необходимо использовать в конкретных ситуациях.

---

Попал сюда -> **[TEncoding (Delphi) - пример](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/TEncoding_(Delphi))**

В этом примере определяется кодировка исходного файла, а затем файл записывается в любой выбранной кодировке. Используйте этот проект для создания файлов любой кодировки. В этом примере требуется два текстовых редактирования и поле со списком.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LByteOrderMark: TBytes;
  LOffset: Integer;
  LEncoding, DestEncoding: TEncoding;
  LFileStream: TFileStream;
  EncodingArray: array[0..5] of TEncoding;
begin
  LEncoding:= nil;
  EncodingArray[0]:= TEncoding.UTF8;
  EncodingArray[1]:= TEncoding.UTF7;
  EncodingArray[2]:= TEncoding.Unicode;
  EncodingArray[3]:= TEncoding.Default;
  EncodingArray[4]:= TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
  EncodingArray[5]:= TEncoding.ASCII;
  DestEncoding := EncodingArray[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];
  LFileStream := TFileStream.Create(Edit1.Text, fmOpenRead);
  try
    // Read file into buffer.
    SetLength(LBuffer, LFileStream.Size);
//    LFileStream.Read(LBuffer[0], Length(LBuffer));
    LFileStream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(LBuffer)^, Length(LBuffer));

    // Identify encoding and convert buffer to UTF8.
    LOffset := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(LBuffer, LEncoding);
//    for I := 0 to Length(LBuffer) - 1 do
//      Memo1.Lines.Add((LBuffer[I]));
    LBuffer := LEncoding.Convert(LEncoding, DestEncoding, LBuffer,
      LOffset, Length(LBuffer) - LOffset);
  finally
    LFileStream.Free;
  end;

  LFileStream := TFileStream.Create(Edit2.Text, fmCreate);
  try
    // Write an encoding byte-order mark and buffer to output file.
    LByteOrderMark := DestEncoding.GetPreamble;
    LFileStream.Write(LByteOrderMark[0], Length(LByteOrderMark));
    LFileStream.Write(LBuffer[0], Length(LBuffer));
  finally
    LFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   with ComboBox1, Items do begin
     Add('TEncoding.UTF8');
     Add('TEncoding.UTF7');
     Add('TEncoding.Unicode');
     Add('TEncoding.Default');
     Add('TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode');
     Add('TEncoding.ASCII');
     ItemIndex := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Я не претендую на верный ответ, но если с чего и можно было бы начать, я думаю с этих примеров. Я думаю не составит труда обернуть этот проект, записи в любую кодировку, под свои намерения.

---

### StringCodePage

Подпрограммой StringCodePage будет возвращаться значение Word, которое соответствует кодовой странице для заданной строки.

```
procedure TForm88.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  // Кодовая страница для ANSI-кириллицы - 1251
  CyrillicString = type AnsiString(1251);
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: UnicodeString;
  U8: UTF8String;
  C: CyrillicString;
begin
  A := 'This is an AnsiString';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('AnsiString Codepage: ' + IntToStr(StringCodePage(A)));
  U := 'This is a UnicodeString';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('UnicodeString Codepage: ' + IntToStr(StringCodePage(U)));
  U8 := 'This is a UTF8string';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('UTF8string Codepage: ' + IntToStr(StringCodePage(U8)));
  C := 'This is a CyrillicString';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('CyrillicString Codepage: ' + IntToStr(StringCodePage(C)));
end;
```

Результат выполнения:

```
The Codepage for an AnsiString is: 1252
The Codepage for an UnicodeString is: 1200
The Codepage for an UTF8string is: 65001
The Codepage for an CyrillicString is: 1251
```

**Оригинальная статья** - **[Delphi in a Unicode World Part II](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38498)**

Comment: эт все не то StringCodePage привязана к типам данных а не к самой(что находится в строке) а прочесть файл в разных кодировках это тож не то. я за автоматику а там еще выбирать нужно руками кодировку. все что я понял лежит в вопросе . просто нужные диапозоны выставить нужно. но я думаю есть что то готовое чем самому каждый байт проверять сохранится он в анси или надо utf брать

Comment: @vegat4 я ещё подумывал на этот вариант, дико конечно, но у python из коробки есть те фичи которые вам нужны - https://blogs.embarcadero.com/ru/getting-started-wit-python4delphi/